# Relational database structure for Texas Hold'em poker data

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I am planning a relational database to store poker game data (like what would be included in the hand histories). I would like help figuring out how to design the associations. It seems like there should be 4 models: Game, Hand, Player, and Action (single action of a given player, like raise, fold, call).  Let me lay out what I have:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hands
  has_many :actions
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players
end

class Hand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :actions
  belongs_to :game
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players
end

class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :hand
  belongs_to :player
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :games
  has_and_belongs_to_many :hands
  has_many :actions
end
```

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're planning to use `has_and_belongs_to_many`, you should probably switch to using `has_many ..., :through` as it's much easier to manage. You already have an Action model that does what you need without having to create some join tables:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hands
end

class Hand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :actions
  belongs_to :game

  has_many :players,
    :through => :actions,
    :source => :player
end

class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :hand
  belongs_to :player
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :actions
  has_many :played_games,
    :through => :actions,
    :as => :game
  has_many :played_hands,
    :through => :actions,
    :as => :hand
end
```

Generally, the fewer tables you have involved in your queries, the faster they will run. Involving any kind of `JOIN` is going to lead to unpredictable query performance.

Be sure to index your tables carefully, and use the `EXAMINE` statement to ensure you're hitting indexes when using them. Table scans will be extremely painful if you load this up with millions of records, and that doesn't take long in games like this as a single hand involves dozens of actions and it's typical to play dozens of hands every hour.

Comment: Hi Tadman, thank you for your help - this was very useful.  I understand how you set up the Game, Hand, and Action models, but I'm still a bit unclear about the Player model. Could you explain what the Player table would look (i.e. which foreign keys are included)? Is it that there is a played_hands column with hand_id values in it?  Also, would you mind explaining why game is only associated with hands?  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You can navigate from Game through to Player if you follow the links, like `game.hands.first.players` or by creating your own custom query to join that for you more efficiently. Also, a `has_many ..., :through` relationship does not involve a new column, it will work by leveraging an existing relationship. In the example you've given, the `players` table only needs an `id` column to work, the rest is up to you. Action is where all the relationships are defined.

Answer (score 1):

Makes sense as a first draft.  Associations arising from what you have give the following tables and keys:

```
Game       :: Game_id (PK);....
Hand       :: Hand_id (PK); Game_id (FK);....
Player     :: Player_id (PK); Action_id (FK);
ActionType :: ActionType_id (PK); Type;
(Note this table will only have three records - raise, fold, call)
Action     :: Action_id (PK); ActionType_id (FK); Game_id (FK); Hand_id (FK); Player_id (FK);....
PlayerHand :: Player_id (FK); Hand_id (FK); Has_or_Belongs; (PK is (Player_id, Hand_id))
GamePlayer :: Game_id (FK); Player_id (FK); Has_or_Belongs; (PK is (Game_id, Player_id))
```

Comment: It'll be better to use an integer or enum to categorize the ActionType.